# How to merge table objects by column names?

Tags: r, merge, rbind

We can merge two data frames by column names with `merge()`.

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=9, b=7)
d2 <- data.frame(a=6, b=5, c=5)

merge(d1, d2, all=TRUE)
#   a b  c
# 1 6 5  5
# 2 9 7 NA
```

But I'm facing unexpected difficulties with table objects.

```
t1 <- table(mtcars[1:16, 10])
t2 <- table(mtcars[-(1:16), 10])
```

My attempts failed so far:

```
# fails
merge(t1, t2, all=TRUE)
merge(t(t1), t(t2), all=TRUE)
merge(as.data.frame(t1), as.data.frame(t2), all=TRUE)
rbind(t1, t2)
data.table::rbindlist(t1, t2)
Reduce(function(x, y) 
  merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by=intersect(names(x), names(y))), list(t1, t2))
```

This one's working, but it's way too clumsy:

```
tmp <- merge(t(as.data.frame(t1)), t(as.data.frame(t2)), all=TRUE)
names(tmp) <- unlist(tmp[1, ])
tmp <- `rownames<-`(tmp[-1, ], NULL)
tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, as.numeric)
tmp
```

**Expected output:**

```
#   3 4  5
# 1 9 7 NA
# 2 6 5  5
```

**How in base R can we efficiently merge table objects by column names to get a data.frame?**

*Note:* I'm probably asking a duplicate, but so-called "table" solutions are actually always linked to a "data.frame" issue.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use tables instead of data.frames?

Comment: @Ben373 I'm not sure if I understand the point of your question.

Comment: The function `table` is used to make contingency tables and does not return a `data.frame` class object. The function `merge` only merges `data.frame` class objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the unique names of each of the provided tables we can use those to subset each name from the tables.  This function *should* expand to use any number of tables, but I only tested it with your sample data

```
merge.tables <- function(...) {
  tables = list(...)
  table.names = unique(unlist(sapply(tables, names)))
  merged = sapply(table.names, function(nm) { 
    sapply(tables, function(tbl) tbl[nm])
  })
  row.names(merged) = 1:nrow(merged)
  merged
}
merge.tables(t1, t2)
```